# Problem with My First DTD

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

Hy!

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE email [
<!ELEMENT email (von,zu,titel,text,prior)>
<!ELEMENT von (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT zu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT titel (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST prior type (#PCDATA) #REQUIRED >
]>
<email>
<von>test@test.com</von>
<zu>xxx@xxx.com</zu>
<titel>Hello</titel>
<text>Dear John....;-).</text>
<prior type="schnell"/>
</email>
```

Error:

```
The name token is required in the enumerated type list for the "type" attribute declaration.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!ATTLIST prior type CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttType for attribute types, there is no PCDATA there. Also, no need for brackets and #

Answer (score 0):

```
<!ELEMENT prior EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST prior type NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
```

Not only do you need to modify your ATTLIST declaration for `prior`, you also need to add the element declaration for `prior`. I used a type other than `CDATA` for the `type` attribute, just so you could see something different.